# Include HTML is not working, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a separate file for my `navigationbar`, so when there need to be [w3 schools include HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp)

But it is not working, I tried everything. Can someone please help me?

```js
function includeHTML() {
    var z, i, elmnt, file, xhttp;
    /* Loop through a collection of all HTML elements: */
    z = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
        elmnt = z[i];
        /*search for elements with a certain atrribute:*/
        file = elmnt.getAttribute("include-html");
        if (file) {
            /* Make an HTTP request using the attribute value as the file name: */
            xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4) {
                    if (this.status == 200) {elmnt.innerHTML = this.responseText;}
                    if (this.status == 404) {elmnt.innerHTML = "Page not found.";}
                    /* Remove the attribute, and call this function once more: */
                    elmnt.removeAttribute("include-html");
                    includeHTML();
                }
            }
            xhttp.open("GET", file, true);
            xhttp.send();
            /* Exit the function: */
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!--Media-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <!-- Title -->
    <title>Cleo Boonstra</title>
    <script src="IncludeHTML.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div include-html="NavigationBar.html"></div>

</body>
<script>
    includeHTML();
</script>

</html>
```

[This is the error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZGFJ.png)

On my other website, everything is working fine, I just copied the code.
I just want to have every other HTML page of my site have the same `navigation bar, without changing every single` navigation bar on every page.

Comment: [it is not working](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) isn't a useful description of the problem, you need to [do some debugging](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/) and report the results in the question.

Comment: It doesn't work in this snippet because the JavaScript is inserted at the end, so when you call `includeHTML();`, it doesn't exist yet. But in your HTML you show that the HTML is inserted _before_ the `includeHTML();` call, so it should work fine. Does your browser console show any errors? (Btw, Java and JavaScript are very different languages. It doesn't make sense to have a `.java` extension to a JavaScript file.)

Comment: Also strongly recommended to make an array and one function. Then call the function in the succes if there are more elements in the array. Do not loop Ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!--Media-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div data-includeHTML="NavigationBar.html"></div>
</body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("div[data-includeHTML]").each(function () {
            $(this).load($(this).attr("data-includeHTML"));
        });
    });
</script>

</html>
```